# shared measurement units

Tags: science-based, physics, aliens, communication

How do individuals or small groups connected by a radio or similar connection, one or both having minimal tools agree on a system of measurement. Assume no communication problems.  Do not assume shared culture or race (no assuming their feet or screwdrivers are the same length) precision should be at least good enough for trade and navigation.

For clarity, don't bother mentioning metrics or physical constants unless you can call a highschool graduate and tell him how to base a ruler on that over the phone.

Assume transportation difficulties, ship wrecks or distance or something.  (the store is out of reach)
Don't assume the individuals communication tools are things they built instead of purchased or found.
Assume they are on the same planet, not necessarily Earth. 
Don't assume either knows where they are or has fast transportation and a way to trace the radio or whatever.

Don't assume either has a ruler, they might each be able to guess near the length of their radio in their favorite set of units.

I'm asking about what is possible.    Does it maybe appear too story based because I'm trying to ask broadly to draw multiple usable answers so solutions will be of benefit to many?

Based on this being my first question, being on hold, and recieveing brilliant answers and comments that made it clear I had asked badly; rather than try to fix this I'm going to close and try again.  I thank everyone for their responses.

Comment: They both have enough tools and enough knowledge of physics to make a radio, don't they? Because if they simply bought their radios from the store they can go to the same store and buy a ruler and a weighing scale.

Comment: Ah, they are both on Earth? And one of them is shipwrecked? Then just send a rescue ship to fish them out and make sure it carries rulers and scales. And please edit the question so that we understand how this problem came about, because I for one cannot understand what's the difficulty. If they are both on Earth then there is no need to agree on units -- one will physically send their units to the other.

Comment: they can synchronize time intervals. And if they are on one planet the gravity is about the same in their case, so they can make a pendulum. Its frequency depends on the length of the rope and gravity, so they probably can realistically establish the same length with 1% precision. They can establish angular units by observing stars and the sun. time units over ratio.

Comment: I like the pendulum.   How much error could on planet differances in gravity impart?(like between Marianas and Everest )

Comment: +- 50 milligals in average https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Geoids_sm.jpg ; "Effective gravity on the Earth's surface varies by around 0.7%" - from [wiki, Gravity of Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth)

Comment: I see you edited your question to mention that you would like to try again with a different question. For something like that I recommend giving the [Sandbox] on our [Meta] Site a try. You can post your question draft as an answer to the post I linked and wait for feedback in the form of comments. People will not answer the question, but give you feedback on the general stuff, such as on-topic/off-topic, grammar, punctuation, possible duplicates, ways to formulate the question, etc. All this general stuff. Be sure to wait at least 24 hours to give people in different timezones a chance to help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The  [Hydrogen line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line). ~ 21 cm. Not so simple to measure, but it should be possible for any advanced space-faring race to compute and if radio works then we're in the same universe, at least with respect to the electromagnetic spectrum & the speed of light, so the result will the same. That takes care of length. Time can be derived as well (frequency of the Hydrogen line = 1420405751.7667 per second).

This was included on the [Pioneer Plaque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_plaque#Hyperfine_transition_of_neutral_hydrogen).

As I understand it (and I am not a physicist so I don't understand it 100% but that also means other non-physicists have a good chance of being able to understand it, including high school graduates), essentially this involves associating a well-defined physics phenomena - the transition of electrons in a hydrogen atom - with an electromagnetic signature that has been detected. That is the hard part - needs physicists working with space-age technology to figure out what it means, but once they figure out the concepts involved, there is a measurable physical constant associated with it - the wavelength of the electromagnetic signature. Anyone who knows the speed of light in a vacuum can translate a frequency into a wavelength. Plus, in this particular case it is a human-scale (and presumably other sentient life as well) number, not nanometers or light-years.

Comment: computing requires what tools?   humans may not count as an advanced space-faring race but we're reasonably bright and I'm relatively well educated, tell me how.

Comment: can you provide some more flesh to this answer?

Comment: I can, but not right now - time to get paid work done :-(

Comment: @Darkhorse - I consider humans as "advanced space-faring race" - In theory you could have a space-faring race (brute force rockets) and very minimal radio without getting to physics of a level of the Hydrogen line, but I think it kind of all fits together as a general level of science/technology.

Comment: The hydrogen line is a very strong electromagnetic radiation spectral line which can be easily detected by any civilization which has radio. It is powerful enough to be detectable as noise by ordinary receivers in the [UHF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra_high_frequency) [L band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_band). Its wavelength and frequency are known to very great precision.

Comment: This is an exciting possibly, but I want to know how you detected its length last time you did it and how much precision your method achieved.

Comment: @Darkhorse: You don't understand. The wavelength and frequency of the hydrogen line _are well known_. One party says that for them the wavelength of the hydrogen line is 21.1061140542 centimeters; the other knows that _for them_ it's 8.309493722 inches. Now they know how to convert one's centimeters to the other's inches.

Comment: @AlexP You don't understand.  I asked my wife she's never heard of it.  we're talking about individuals .   She's bright enough to Google but then if that doesn't imply she has GPS, she has to measure  and she didn't bring a ruler this weekend.

Comment: @AlexP - I doubt my wife's heard of it either, or 2 out of 3 of my kids. But all can Google "Hydrogen line" and the first entry (Wikipedia) and most of the next several entries give the length (21 cm) near the top of the linked page - some even on the Google results page. So as long as they communicate and the American knows it is 8.3" - and can estimate that based on his hand or foot or radio or whatever and the European knows it is 21cm and can estimate that based on her hand or foot or radio or whatever, they can extrapolate to miles/kilometers etc. and plan their journeys.

Comment: which is great (estamating and extrapolating to a few hundred miles /km  will add a scary amount of error  but maybe close enough to work with )  and if we could assume either  of our individuals are western humans the short side of a piece of writing paper is common and close.   Ship  wreck or anything similar doesn't sound like Google would be available.

Comment: @Darkhorse I think we've got two very different issues here. The one that I am trying to solve - and the other answer as well - is how to come up with a relatively easy to define & use measurement with no cultural relevance. A separate issue is how to replicate that measurement locally - which requires either a lot of advanced equipment (not so easy) or simply a local reference for each person involved - e.g., I'm 6' tall or my paper is Letter (or A4), etc. I think it is reasonable to assume that anyone advanced enough to use radio would have SOME local reference (even if not a simple ruler).

Comment: I think your correct, and I think your answer is brilliant for planned first contact or seti situations.  When I get to a place like that I fully intend to steal it.  I'm looking for something Robinson Caruso can build with two coconuts and the assistance of Friday and a soccer ball named Winston.  The local referents are really useful but I fear the innacuracies.  Over the distance of a 250 mile trip if my paper I thought was A4 turns out to really be Letter size I'm 2 miles off(which is better than I expected to get when I got out my calculator) and my volume unit will be off by 42 cubic in

Comment: @Darkhorse - Then I think we're talking about something totally different from what I was thinking (or the other answer posted). Assuming they are on the same planet and have no technological means to determine relative location (e.g., radio beacons), AND no long distance reliable measurements, then you may have to go off-planet - i.e., navigate by the stars like humans did until relatively recently.

Answer (score 5):

They're talking by **radio** - from that they'll have a **frequency** (from which to devise a time scale) and a **wavelength** (a distance scale) and then from that you can devise energies, temperatures and probably everything else.

For EM waves you have:
$$c=f\lambda$$
With $\lambda$ as the wavelength and $c$ the speed of light. This is assuming they aren't so far apart as to have a red shift in the wavelength but you spoke about a shipwreck so I'm assuming they're on the same planet.

The speed of light is constant so the other two will be too.

Comment: I like this from a simplicity point of view but how accurate to a wavelength are radios? Like will it be exact or do you have a range? I guess you could just pick the middle of that range.

Comment: @FreeElk ±1ppm frequency *stability* is pretty easy, and we can certainly do better than that if necessary. At 1 GHz that means a stability of ±1kHz. (Compare for example the Yaesu FT-897 amateur radio transceiver, which with its optional temperature-controlled crystal oscillator attains a frequency stability of ±0.5ppm and operates up to about 450 MHz.) This doesn't necessarily mean that the *indicated frequency* will be equally *precise*, but most of the time, the accuracy of the displayed value is less important than the precision in maintaining the actual value.